# I'm trying to troubleshoot a syntax error why is my var incorrect on line 2?

Tags: php, html

I'm learning my way through PHP and I followed a tutorial exactly for creating a form that uses PHP to send me an email through the server I'm using but it's not working.

I checked to see if my question has been answered in a way I can understand but I came up empty. I probably just don't know enough about this language but I want to get this feature up and running at least so I can have a way to receive emails without giving out mine.

I have checked to make sure I followed the tutorial correctly and I have. I am missing something key here, I just don't know what.

```
<?php
 if (ifset()$_POST['submit']) {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];

   $mailTo = "https://formspree.io/xoqaovaa"
   $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
   $txt = "you have recieved an E-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;


   mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
   header("Location: contactForm.php?mailsend");

 }
 ?>
```

I expected my contact form to accept inputs from the user in various fields and send those in a message though my server to my email routing service when the user clicks submit button.

What happens when I go to the page is this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in /storage/ssd5/051/11462051/public_html/PHP/master.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the function is `isset()`, not `ifset()`. And you have the `)` in the wrong place. It should be:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

And then you are missing the terminating `;` at this line:

```
$mailTo = "https://formspree.io/xoqaovaa"
```

Comment: awesome ty now I have a new error though.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$headers' (T_VARIABLE) in /storage/ssd5/051/11462051/public_html/PHP/master.php on line 9

Comment: You're missing the `;` on the line before it.

Comment: oh silly me lol tyvm

Comment: well looks good. now I can test the routing service. I'd up vote you but I'm so new i cant yet so i'll kudos you here